# PyTorch autograd: Efficient computation of Jacobian and Jacobian-Vector-product of scalar function over range of inputs

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, jax, autograd

I have function which takes 5 values as arguments and returns a scalar. That is a mapping of the form `f:R^5 -> R`.

Hench, its **Jacobian** `J` is a matrix with dimension `(1x5)` and might as well have been a **row vector** in the form of a **gradient** `g`.

I can easily compute the Jacobian for a single input of `x` using `torch.autograd.functional.jacobian`:

```
J = torch.autograd.functional(func=f, inputs=(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]))
```

Now, my questions are:

1. What is the most efficient way to compute the Jacobian (gradient) multiple times when I have a range of values for one of the arguments?
2. I do not need the gradient on it's own for each of the values in the range. But I would like to multiply the Jacobian `J` with a vector
   `v` and get another vector (elementwise) `y=Jv` of same dimention. Can I make the code more performant by using other functions such as `jvp`, `vjp`, or `vmap`?
3. I've seen then mentioning of Jax other places. Is it better at these of problems?

I've made a small example showing what I am trying to acomplish below - just without using a loop or list comperhension.

```
import torch

def f(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4):
        return x0 ** 2 + x1 ** 3 + x2 ** 4 + x3 ** 5 + x4 ** 6

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = torch.tensor(1.0)
    b = torch.tensor(1.0)
    c = torch.tensor(1.0)
    d = torch.tensor(1.0)
    e = torch.tensor(1.0)

    g = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(func=f, inputs=(a, b, c, d, e))
    print(g)  
    """ (tensor(1.), tensor(2.), tensor(3.), tensor(4.), tensor(5.)) """

    x0_values = torch.arange(1.0, 10.0, 1.0)

    g_list = []
    for x0 in x0_values:
        g = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(func=f, inputs=(x0, b, c, d, e))
        g_list.append(torch.hstack(g))

    J = torch.vstack(g_list)
    print(J)

    """
    tensor([[2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
            [4., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
            [6., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
            [8., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
            [10., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
            [12., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
            [14., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
            [16., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
            [18., 3., 4., 5., 6.]])
    """
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged `jax` and asked about `vmap`, here's how you can do the equivalent computation using `jax.vmap` in place of your loops:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4):
  return x0 ** 2 + x1 ** 3 + x2 ** 4 + x3 ** 5 + x4 ** 6

a = b = c = d = e = jnp.float32(1.0)

g = jax.jacobian(f, argnums=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))(a, b, c, d, e)
print(g)
# (Array(2., dtype=float32), Array(3., dtype=float32), Array(4., dtype=float32),
#  Array(5., dtype=float32), Array(6., dtype=float32))

x0 = jnp.arange(1.0, 10.0)

J = jax.vmap(
    jax.jacobian(f, argnums=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)),
    in_axes=(0, None, None, None, None)
)(x0, b, c, d, e)

print(jnp.column_stack(J))
# [[ 2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [ 4.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [ 6.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [ 8.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [10.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [12.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [14.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [16.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [18.  3.  4.  5.  6.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For you example, you would do something like this

```py
import torch

# rewrite function to be broadcasted
def f(x, pows):
    return x.pow(pows).sum(-1)

# create batch of inputs with `requires_grad=True`
inputs = torch.ones(9,5)
inputs[:,0] = torch.arange(1.0, 10.0, 1.0)
inputs.requires_grad_(True);

# compute output
pows = torch.tensor([2,3,4,5,6])
output = f(inputs,pows)

# call backward
output.backward(torch.ones(output.shape))

print(inputs.grad)
>tensor([[ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [ 4.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [ 6.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [ 8.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [10.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [12.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [14.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [16.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
         [18.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]])
```